# Can you use sodium metabisulphite that is hard

Tags: sanitation, cleaning

I have a container of sodium metabisulphite for sterilizing my fermenter and bottles that has gone hard. It is about 1 year old.

Can I still use this effectively or should I use another container that is still soft that I bought last week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's gone hard, it just means that it's picked up moisture from the air. If you can break off the required amount and it dissolves in water, then it will still be effective.

Comment: You can do what I do with campden tablets.  Put some in the bowl of a spoon, put another spoon on top, and crush it.

Comment: OK thanks guys. The home brew store said to throw it away and get some more. I have noticed that since it has gone hard it doesn't have the same strong smell as the fresh sodium metabisulphite so I have been using slightly more than usual.

Comment: If they told you to buy more, it's probably because they *sell* it. Using a bit more is probably fine. In the future, you could try putting a few grains of rice wrapped up in a piece of cloth to absorb any moisture in the container.